# How to programmatically scroll HTML elements in a QWebView?

Tags: html, qt, webkit

I'm developing a browser with touch screen support using Qt 5.4 and WebKit (I'm not using QML at the moment). Currently I'm implementing the touch scrolling and so far I managed to scroll the page's main frame. However, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to scroll its HTML sub-elements such as iframe, textarea, div, etc.
This is because I know how to scroll the main frame (I can call `webView->page()->mainFrame()->setScrollPosition(QPoint(x, y));`), but not how to scroll the web elements.

I imagine that with JavaScript injection it might be possible to check if an HTML element is scrollable and call a function that scrolls it, but this doesn't seem to be that elegant. Is there a way to this using only C++/Qt code?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time grappling with this issue. Finally I just used a single line of Javascript and was done with it.

```
webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Plus, if Javascript is such a standard these days, why can't you rely on it inside a `QWebView`?

The Javscript to scroll a web element would be something like:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. However, it seems that this JS scrolls the main frame only (same thing as `webView->page()->mainFrame()->setScrollPosition(QPoint(x, y));`). What if I have to scroll a text area or an iframe?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Again I think you're looking at a snipped of Javascript to do that.